# Adding different values based on which option they choose on Spinner - Android Studio

Tags: android

I am trying to create a app that calculates fuel mileage for racecars. I'm in the very basics of this app right now, I would like to know how to add a formula to each option on the spinner.

For instance I want the formula to be:

thesum= (int) (fulltank-(n1*avglapgal));
thesum1= (int) (thesum-(n2*avglapgal));

I want "avglapgal" (average gallon per lap) to change based on which option they choose on the spinner.

How do I accomplish this?

Thanks in advance!

My strings.xml:

> ```
>     <resources>
>     <string name="app_name">MidTermApp</string>
>     <string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
>     <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
>     <string name="trackname">Choose your Track</string>
>     <string-array name="trackchoices">
>         <item>Short Track (Half mile)</item>
>         <item>Intermediate (Mile)</item>
>         <item>Speedway (1.5 miles)</item>
>         <item>Super-Speedways (2.5 miles)</item>
>     </string-array>
> </resources>
> ```

My JAVA file:

> package com.example.fuelapp;
>
> import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity; import
>   android.os.Bundle; import android.view.Menu; import
>   android.view.MenuItem; import android.view.View; import
>   android.widget.EditText; import android.widget.Spinner; import
>   android.widget.TextView;
>
> import java.text.DecimalFormat;
>
> public class Grade{
>       String mLabel;
>       Float mValue;
>       ....... } public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
>       double fulltank=18.5;
>       double avglapgal=.25;
>
> ```
> @Override
> protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
>
> }
>
> public void onButtonClick(View v)
> {
>     int n1;
>     int n2;
>     int thesum;
>     double thesum1;
>     EditText e1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.lapscomplete);
>     EditText e2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.lapstogo);
>     TextView t1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.answer);
>     n1=Integer.parseInt(e1.getText().toString());
>     n2=Integer.parseInt(e2.getText().toString());
>     thesum= (int) (fulltank-(n1*avglapgal));
>     thesum1= (int) (thesum-(n2*avglapgal));
>     final Spinner trackchoose = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.tracks);
>     DecimalFormat currency = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
>     String choice = trackchoose.getSelectedItem().toString();
>     t1.setText("You'll have " + currency.format(thesum1) + " gallon(s) of gas remaining.");
> }
>
>   @Override
> public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
>     // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
>     getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
>     return true;
> }
>
> @Override
> public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
>     // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
>     // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
>     // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
>     int id = item.getItemId();
>
>     //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
>     if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
>         return true;
>     }
>
>     return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
> } }
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do two things:

- You need to set a `ListAdapter` on the `Spinner` to provide a source for the choices.  Since you already have a `String` array, you can use `ArrayAdapter<String>`.
- You need to set an `OnItemSelectedListener` on the `Spinner` to respond to the user action.  The `onItemSelected()` method will tell you which item the user chose.

Please see this great example on Android Developers:  [Spinners | Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html)

Comment: Thanks for the response! Forgive me as I am quite the noob when it comes to this android stuff. I looked over and read the link you provided and I'm just not catching on I guess.